# error rotate image in android , image missing

Tags: android

I have code to rotate image like this

```
private void rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {


        // create new matrix     
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // setup rotation degree
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
        Bitmap ro = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(ro);
        recycleBitmap();
    }
```

It work to rotate , but if I click rotate button continuously , my Image is not vissible , How to solve this? thanks

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: And what's `b`?  How are you really calling it taking the bitmap from the image?  Give a few actual lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the postScale before the postRotate

```
 // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);
```

Comment: scaleWidth is bitmap.getWidth() ??

Comment: Yeah: bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight()

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your code is changing the martrix value each time you click on the rotate button.Changing values continuously may destroy the structure of the image.You can adjust or scale the matrix.Try this'

```
private void rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {
        // create new matrix     
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

 matrix.postRotate(degree,px,py);//(px,py)is pivot point with reference to which the image is rotated
        // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
        Bitmap ro = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(ro);
        recycleBitmap();
    }
```

Comment: px and py can be any int value, try to make it the mid point of screen

Comment: like what ? can u give me that example??

Comment: px=src.getWidth()    ,py= src.getWidth()/2